# Instalacion MySQL

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de descargar e instalar MySQL ya tenia todo listo pero en los requerimientos me decia que necesitaba tener Python 3.4 y Visual Studio, entonces lo que hice fue descargar la ultima version de Python y aun asi me seguia diciendo que necesitaba Python 3.4 e intente descargar la version antigua (3.4) y me seguia diciendo lo mismo ¿Por que ocurre esto? ¿Realmente es necesario tener instalado Python y Visual Studio? de antemano, gracias.

Comment: ¿De dónde has descargado MySQL?¿Podrías incluir más detalles y capturas de pantalla? MySQL no necesita Python ni Visual Studio, suena realmente raro.

Comment: Lo mas raro es que python y visual studio no se nombran juntos jaja

Comment: Te sugiero que descargues MySQL desde la pagina official: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ - En la documentación (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html) menciona que solo requiere `Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package`

Comment: ya agregue una imagen a la descripcion de mi problema @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: @JUANCALVOPINAM  Si descargue MySQL de la pagina oficial y como quiera me dice que requiero Python

Comment: ¿Estás intentando hacer una instalación completa o algo? Esos dos productos son extensiones de MySQL y no MySQL en sí. Prueba a hacer una instalación personalizada y selecciona sólo lo que necesites.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Ya estoy en eso, pero como no entiendo para que es cada cosa, me podrias decir que seria lo esencial que tendria que descargar?

Comment: ¿Te has descargado el [instalador para Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Si

Comment: Yo ya lo tenía instalado de antes y no me sale lo mismo que a ti (me sale el _upgrader_). Intenta añadir más información con los pasos que pones para la instalación (con capturas de pantalla) y seguro que encontramos dónde está el problema. Pero sinceramente, no veo motivo para que te pida instalar esas dos cosas